# Execute system cron manually

Tags: 7, cron

How to execute [system](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_cron/7.x) cron manually via drush or drupal UI?

Comment: To confirm you just want to run the one cron hook and not the others?

Comment: to be specific about my requirement, I want to execute the cron that deletes the unused or not-permanent files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute *just* the [`system_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_cron/7.x) hook, the easiest way is with drush

```
$ drush php-eval 'system_cron();'
```

This will start a PHP process, boostrap Drupal, and run the input.  Note that this will run everything that this hook does, in addition to the file cleanup, including garbabe collection on the various database tables with ephemeral data, like `{cache}`, `{batch}`, `{flood}`, etc.  There isn't an individual function in Drupal 7 that just handles the file cleanup.

Also keep in mind that when you run drush like this, you are running as the user who you logged in as.  This user may or may not have persmissions on the files and tmp directories in order to delete files.

You could copy this code into your own script and then do

```
$ drush scr cleanup-the-files.php
```

Comment: Thanks :) One more question I have is where can I get the history of cron executed? i.e. past all times when it got executed

Comment: @meen When the full cron runs, it will create an entry in {watchdog}.  So, if that is enabled on your site, you will see it in the **Recent Log Messgaes**.  If you run a cron hook individually, like I show above, it may or may not get logged.  `system_cron()` doesn't log anything, unless it has problems deleting system files.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `drush core-cron` it will do the trick

Comment: Don't know how but it worked first time. but when tried again twice it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Configuration->System->Cron Settings(admin/config/system/cron), you can see system_cron listed here. Execute this cron by clicking on run link corresponding to the same.

Comment: system_cron not listed.

Comment: Ok. So can u please confirm any other crons are listing there? If not it may be any permission issue.. Please try below URL YOUR_SITE_URL/admin/config/system/cron/execute/system_cron